# Error during date/time conversion no date

Tags: sql, datetime-format

The last field ***STEPCD*** is a `varchar(10)`.

If i remove the where statement `smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS.STEPCD = '10006'` the query runs fine. But when I add this in I get the error:

```
 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Where is this date/time error coming from if the STEP code is varchar?

```
Select CP_Population.*, CHRTNO,PRSNTINGCOMPL,DISPOCD,

CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.ARRVDATE AS datetime)    
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.ARRVTIME AS time), 120) AS [ED_Arrival_dtime],

CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHDATE AS datetime)    
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHTIME AS time), 120) AS [ED_Discharge_dtime],

DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.ARRVDATE AS datetime)    
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.ARRVTIME AS time), 120),
CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHDATE AS datetime)    
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHTIME AS time), 120)) AS [ED_Arrival to ED_Discharge],

CASE 
WHEN CP_Population.vst_type_cd = 'O' 
THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHDATE AS datetime)   
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHTIME AS time), 120), CP_Population.op_released)*1.0/60  
WHEN CP_Population.vst_type_cd = 'I' 
THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHDATE AS datetime)   
+ CAST(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DSCHTIME AS time), 120), CP_Population.vst_end_dtime)*1.0/60           ELSE NULL END 
As [Unit_LOS],
STEPCD

FROM CP_Population INNER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART
ON right('00' + smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.VISITNO,12) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS     = CP_Population.pt_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS ON smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.CHRTNO =     smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS.CHARTNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_DISPO ON smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_CHART.DISPOCD =   smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_DISPO.CODE

WHERE TYPE = 'A'
AND smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS.STEPCD = '10006' <--ERROR
```

Comment: Looks like it is a datetime column but you are passing invalid date

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bad record in your STEPCD Column, if you are using SQL 2012, try using TRY_CONVERT and check results to see what row returns null, that will be your dirty record.

Other option you can try is by adding below where clause to your query

```
WHERE TYPE = 'A'
AND smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS.STEPCD = '10006' 
AND ISDATE(smsdss.c_cfvhs_EMSTAT_ORDERS.STEPCD) = 0
```